# Convertir parametro de una funcion automaticamente a string

Tags: javascript, array, string, function

Quisiera crear una funcion que tenga como parametros el nombre de un array y cualquier string. El objetivo es que solo con meter los nombres de ambas cosas, la funcion logee el index del item, si es que existe dentro de la array **(sin necesidad de tener que usar comillas a la hora de especificar el item cuando llamo la funcion)**. Aqui les dejo el codigo de lo que mas o menos queria lograr

```
function findId (array, item) {
    let stringedItem = String(item)
    let index = array.indexOf(stringedItem)
    console.log(index)
}

const array1 = ['objeto1', 'objeto2', 'objeto3'];
findId(array1, objeto3)
```

*pd. soy nuevo con la programacion, lo digo por si esta duda es muy basica o algo por el estilo haha. Gracias a quien sea pueda contestarme :)... Ah, y encontre `string()`en un blog online, honestamente no se exactamente que hace, solo entiendo que puede convertir todo a una string*

Comment: Creo que no se puede hacer eso que quieres, si colocas `findId(array1, objeto3)` estarías enviando un objeto que no existe en tu definición. Además de que no se puede acceder a los nombres de las variables y convertirlas a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findId (array, item) {
    let stringedItem = String(item)
    let index = array.indexOf(stringedItem)
    console.log(index)
}

const array1 = ['objeto1', 'objeto2', 'objeto3'];
var word="objeto3";
findId(array1, word);
```

la unica solucion posible que se me ocurre es almacenar la palabra en una variable asi te evitas usar comillas en los parametros. en mi opinion no parece ser algo eficiente

Comment: Tienes razón que la respuesta no es muy practica, pero me ayudó! Gracias :)

Comment: Me alegra saberlo, suerte